# Install Chrome My WD 4TB hard drive doesn't work on Windows, on Ubuntu it says unclean file system

Tags: windows, filesystem, external-hdd

I was copying few files from my phone to my external hard drive. And my laptop froze so I had to remove the cable without unmounting. When I plugged it again my explorer froze. I have tried several other PC's but it still freezes. Then I tried mounting my drive on Ubuntu and it gives me a message

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/wd
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
```

After fixing it shows up in file manager and I am able to access the files but when I plug it into Windows it freezes again and then when I try it Ubuntu the same error appears.

Answer (score 2):

Have the file system on your external hard drive checked using the Windows drive checking tools. Once the file system is healthy, Ubuntu and MS Windows will correctly work with it.

To keep your file system in a healthy condition, make sure to unmount it explicitly each time. In Ubuntu, you can right-click the partition in the left pane of the file manager and select "Safely remove" or "Unmount". In Windows, there is an icon in the tray allowing to unmount a removable drive. Alternatively, a drive will be correctly closed when you **fully** shut the system down (i.e. no "stand-by" or "sleep" or "hibernate", but a full shut down.

In addition, have the partition periodically checked in Windows.

Background: ntfs is a proprietary file system of Microsoft. Although Ubuntu has very good support to work with the ntfs file system, it does not have all the tools to vigorously repair a damaged ntfs file system. Therefore, the Ubuntu operating system will refuse to mount a damaged "unclean" file system. Although it is possible in most cases to fix the partition in linux with the `ntfsfix` utility, it is advised to fix ntfs partitions from within MS Windows.